# Javascript subtraction and multiplication to two decimal places using html forms

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm new to javascripting and would like a little help with a form that I'm creating if that's at all possible.

I'd like to work out how much the customer would save from buying through us per item and per year based on the following piece of code.

The form is as follows:

```
<div>
    <h2>Current Price:</h2>
        <input type='text' name='currentprice' id='currentprice' placeholder='Current Price' />
</div>
    <div class="ourinput">
    <h4>Our Price:</h4>
    <input type='text' name='ourprice' id='ourprice' placeholder='Our Price' />
</div>
<div>
    <h2>Annual Volume:</h2>
    <input type='text' name='annualvolume' id='annualvolume' placeholder='Annual Volume (approx)' />
</div>
<div>
    <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
    <button id="roll" onclick="RP()">Click Here For Magic</button>
</div>
<div class="ourinput">
    <h4>Saving Per Item:</h4>
    <input type='text' name='differenceprice' id='differenceprice' placeholder='Saving Per Item' />
</div>
<div class="ourinput">
    <h4>Annual Saving:</h4>
    <input type='text' name='annualsaving' id='annualsaving' placeholder='Annual Saving' />
</div>
```

With my limited knowledge and doing a lot of searching I've managed to get this piece of javascript working but I need it to 2 decimal places as well as working out the annual saving.

The code that I already have is:

```
<script language="javascript">

function RP() {
var currentprice = document.getElementById('currentprice').value;

var tennantsprice = document.getElementById('ourprice').value;

var answer = currentprice - ourprice;

document.getElementById('differenceprice').value = answer;

}
</script>
```

This code works to subtract ourprice from currentprice but I just don't know enough about it to go any further.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var answer = Number(currentprice) - Number(ourprice);
```

Since `currentprice` and `ourprice` are string you need to parse it to `int` or `float` or `Number`.

You can use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` functions based on your priority. If you want the two decimal places to be fixed try the below code.

```
 var answer = (Number(currentprice) - Number(ourprice)).toFixed(2);
 var annualvolume = document.getElementById('annualvolume').value;
 var annualSaving = (answer * Number(annualvolume)).toFixed(2);
 document.getElementById('annualsaving').value = annualSaving;
```

[toFixed() reference.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)

Comment: Thanks, I would only like the final value to be 2 decimal places, if i use this code it still comes out with a ridiculous amount of decimal places, also  in the same click can it be multiplied by the annualvolume box in order to work out how much the customer would save over the course of a year?

Comment: OK I've got that bit working, how do I then multiply that answer by Annual Volume and get another answer in the Annual Saving box? you're a lifesaver already, Thanks.

Comment: do the same get the value of annual volume and multiply it with answer and set the new value to the annual saving box. Edited the answer

Comment: Thanks, that's sorted it, it makes a lot more sense now!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var newNumber = (Number(myNumber)).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: This way you loose data. You might as well have used `Math.round(number) + ".00"`

Comment: @sabof you're right. I have updated to correct this.